# is that char null terminator is including in the length count

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   char s[]="help";
   printf("%d",strlen(s));  
}
```

Why the above output is  4, isnt that 5 is the correct answer?

it should be  'h','e','l','p','\0' in memory..

Thanks.

Comment: If you used `sizeof(s) / sizeof(char)` you would get the answer you expect.

Comment: @WaleedKhan: True -- when the code is written as above. Unfortunately, seemingly trivial changes (e.g., `char *s="help";`) will break that, so you need to be pretty careful with it. As long as we're at it, `sizeof(char)` is defined to always be 1, so simply `sizeof(s)` would be fine for the code as it is right now.

Comment: Was the documentation for strlen unclear on this matter?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

`strlen`:  Returns the length of the given byte string not including null terminator;

```
char s[]="help";
strlen(s) should return 4.
```

`sizeof`:  Returns the length of the given byte string, include null terminator;

```
char s[]="help";
sizeof(s) should return 5.
```

Comment: Comments are wrong. `sizeof` does return 5: http://pastebin.com/94AbKunk

Comment: Note If the size of the array is known, for example `char s[9] = "help"` then `sizeof` will be 9 not 5 because the rest of the storage will be implicitly initialized with `\0`.

Answer (score 11):

`strlen` counts the elements until it reaches the null character, in which case it will stop counting. It won't include it with the length.

Answer (score 5):

`strlen()` does not count the number of characters in the array (in fact, this might not even be knowable (if you only have a pointer to the memory, instead of an array). It does, as you have found out, count the number of characters up to but not including the null character. Consider `char s[] = {'h','i','\0','t','h','e','r','e'};`

Answer (score 4):

It's 4.

strlen() counts the number of characters up to, but not including, the first char with a value of 0 - the nul terminator.

Answer (score 3):

`strlen(const char* ptr)` returns the length of the string by counting the non-zero elements starting at until reaches zero. So `'\0'` doesn't count.

I recommend that you consult the reference like [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) for questions like this.

It's clearly stated as:

```
 A C string is as long as the number of characters between the beginning 
 of the string and the terminating null character (without including the
 terminating null character itself).
```